# How to properly mock data object for unit tests?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs, jasmine, mocha.js

I'm trying to unit test a chunk of code that looks something like the snippet below.

```
const getSubscriptions = {
     options: {
         async handler({query}) {
             const workType = searchParams.get('workType');

             return axios.get(url, {
                 headers: {
                     Authorization: `Bearer ${clientCredentials.access_token}`
                 }
             }).then((response) => {
                 if (workType && workType.length > 0) {
                     if (workType === 'Unknown') {
                         response.data._embedded = response.data._embedded.filter((subscriptions) => !subscriptions.systemProperties.workType);
                     } else {
                         response.data._embedded = response.data._embedded.filter((subscriptions) => subscriptions.systemProperties.workType && subscriptions.systemProperties.workType === workType);
                     }
                 }

                 return response.data;
             })
         }
     },
method: 'GET',
path: '/subscriptions'};
```

I'm seeing errors such as "cannot read property 'filter' of undefined" in the existing tests after adding the .filter usage. How can I properly mock this in my unit tests so that filter is recognized as a function? Currently the tests are passing in a data object that looks like:

```
data: [chance.object(), chance.object()]
```

I've tried editing this data object to include _embedded and then I get an error that .filter is not a function.

I'm new to writing unit tests for JavaScript, so I've been stuck on this for a while. Any help is appreciated. I'm using Mocha for testing, but can likely interpret a Jasmine or Jest solution as well.

Here is a trimmed down version of the test suite:

```
describe('Get subscriptions', () => {
    const workType = chance.word();

    const getSubscriptionsResponse = {
        data: [chance.object(), chance.object()]
    };

    const expectedRequest = {
        auth: {
            ...expectedAuth
        },
        path: '/subscriptions',
        query: {
            workType
        }
    };

    it('should call API with auth token for Subscriptions', async () => {
        const axiosStub = sinon.stub(axios, 'get').resolves(getSubscriptionsResponse);
        const expectedParams = new URLSearchParams(expectedRequest.query);

        await getSubscriptionsRoute.options.handler(expectedRequest);

        expect(axiosStub).to.have.callCount(1);
        expect(axiosStub).to.be.calledWith(expectedUrl, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `${accessToken}`
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have the mock return an array? You can certainly filter an array. It's not clear how your current test is set up at all, give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry about that. I've updated with more information on the code itself and test setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is trying to filter the `response.data._embedded` array — `response.data` is an object. You should mock the response data to be an object (with the `_embedded` property) and not an array.

```
{
  data: [chance.object(), chance.object()]
}
```

should be

```
{
  data: {
    _embedded: [
      // ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks. I had exactly this, but had an object in embedded rather than array brackets. Much appreciated!